# CAML Query for retrieving only document library items in only one folder

Tags: javascript, document-library, caml-query, folder, subfolders

I'm trying to access the documents in a specific folder in a SharePoint document library. the library has multiple folders but I do know the name of the folder.

here is an example of the file tree (I want to access al the files inside the Folder_4:

- MyDocLib

  - document_Acorn.pdf
  - document_ApplePie.pdf
  - Folder_AppleTypes

    - document_Gala.pdf
    - document_HoneyCrisp.pdf
    - document_PinkLady.pdf
    - document_Jonathan.pdf
  - document_Mango.pdf
  - Folder_OrangeTypes
  - document_Watermellon.pdf

I have this CAML query which will get me the folder but when I try Recursive or RecursiveAll I can never get more than just the folder to show up in the query. I believe I'm doing something wrong in the following query.

```
var camlQuery2 = "<View Scope='Recursive'>" + 
            "<Query>" + 
                "<OrderBy>" + 
                    "<FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True' />" +
                "</OrderBy>" + 
                "<Where>" + 
                    "<Eq>" + 
                        "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" + 
                        "<Value Type='Text'>" +
                            "AppleTypes" + 
                        "</Value>" + 
                    "</Eq>" + 
                "</Where>" + 
            "</Query>" + 
        "</View>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set camlQuery.**FolderServerRelativeUrl** = folder serverRelativeUrl

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
                        <Query>
                        </Query>
                    </View>";
camlQuery.**FolderServerRelativeUrl** = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;

ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.Load(listItems);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

[fdi-sharepoint](http://fdi-sharepoint.e-monsite.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that requires making another query. I change "Recursive" to "RecursiveAll" which will give me the folder I am wanting.

```
var camlQuery1 = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>" + 
        "<Query>" + 
            "<OrderBy>" + 
                "<FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True' />" +
            "</OrderBy>" + 
            "<Where>" + 
                "<Eq>" + 
                    "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" + 
                    "<Value Type='Text'>" +
                        "AppleTypes" + 
                    "</Value>" + 
                "</Eq>" + 
            "</Where>" + 
        "</Query>" + 
    "</View>";
```

From that I will extract the "UniqueId" then I use that Id in a query to get all items with the "ParentUniqueId" that match the UniqueID.

```
var camlQuery2 = "<View Scope='Recursive'>" + 
        "<Query>" + 
            "<OrderBy>" + 
                "<FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True' />" +
            "</OrderBy>" + 
            "<Where>" + 
                "<Eq>" + 
                    "<FieldRef Name='ParentUniqueId'/>" + 
                    "<Value Type='Text'>" +
                        "{A1P2P3L4-E5T6-Y7P8-E9S0-1UNI2QUE3ID4}" + 
                    "</Value>" + 
                "</Eq>" + 
            "</Where>" + 
        "</Query>" + 
    "</View>";
```

This will give only the items inside the folder except other subfolders.